# An arithmetic-progression-free subset with more than 256 elements of $\{0,1,2,...,3^8-1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, arithmetic-progressions, extremal-combinatorics

We say that a set $ A \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $|A|\geq 3$ is *free* if for every $a, b, c \in A$, $a\neq b$ we have $a+ b \neq 2c$.

Show that $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots , 3^8 − 1\}$ contains a *free* subset with more than $256$ elements.

I tried to use a greedy algorithm but I didn't have a clear idea.

Comment: $256=2^8$ cannot be a coincidence...

Comment: Agree.  Smells like some kind of induction.  

By manual inspection, we find the free set $(0,1,3,7,8) \subset (0,1,...,3^2-1)$ of size $5=2^2+1$, establishing out base-case for $n=2$.

Comment: For n=4, we can construct a free set of size $25=5x5$, namely $(0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 27, 28, 30, 34, 35, 63, 64, 66, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 79, 80)$ = $(a+9*b : a,b\in (0,1,3,7,8))$ Needs some rigour to prove why the bigger set is free, given the smaller one, but ironing that out should be the inductive step.

Comment: Hint: Think about writing numbers in base 3. That can lead to an 'easy' find of a free set of 256 numbers. Not sure if it can be tweaked to more.

Comment: $a\neq b\neq c$ doesn't actually mean "$a,b,c$ are all distinct", which I think is what you meant to say. Turns out you don't _need_ to assume that, since if two of them are equal, and $a+b=2c$, then the third is also equal to those two. So it's enough to assume, say, $a\neq b$. But still.

Comment: @DongKy Your set isn't free; $a+b=2c$ holds , *e.g.$, when $a=7$, $b=9$, $c=8$.

Comment: For $n=4$, the maximum is $22$: $$\{0,1,5,6,8,17,19,20,24,25,27,55,57,58,62,63,65,70,74,76,79,80\}$$

Comment: Or, $\{0, 1, 6, 8, 9,$ $13, 19, 21, 22, 24,$ $28, 45, 49, 51, 52,$ $54, 60, 64, 65, 67,$ $72, 73\}$. This is obtained with LPSolve IDE v5.5.2.11 and [A065825](https://oeis.org/A065825/list), where $a(n)$ is "the smallest $k$ such that $n$ numbers may be picked in $\{1,...,k\}$ with no three terms in arithmetic".

Comment: @Apass.Jack For $n=4$ it turns out that there are $3048$ solutions that contain $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A free subset of 256 Cantor numbers

The hints are in the problem statement. "$256=2^8$ cannot be a coincidence ". Moreover, the given numbers are the first consecutive $3^8$ natural numbers.

Let us consider an integral variant of "Cantor numbers", numbers that have only $0$ or $1$ when they are represented in base $3$, i.e. there are no $2$. More formally, let
$$ A=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^7a_i3^i\mid a_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}.$$

Suppose $a,b,c\in A$, $a+b=2c$. Consider the equality in base $3$. Since each digit of $a$ or $b$ or $c$ is at most $1$, there is no carry in the addition of $a+b$ nor in the multiplication of $2c$. Hence the equality holds at each place.

- If $c$ is $0$ at some place, then both $a$ and $b$ must be $0$ at the same place.
- If $c$ is $1$ at some place, then both $a$ and $b$ must be $1$ at the same place.

Hence $a=b=c$. That means $A$ is a free set.

By the way, $A$ is what you will find by the greedy algorithm, as also described in [Mike Earnest's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4664995/580448).

#### One more number

$|A|=2^8$, since there are $2$ options for each $a_i$. This just falls short of the requirement "more than $256$", however.

Let us tweak a bit at the large end of $A$ to make a bigger set.

Consider
$$ B=(A\setminus\{(11111111)_3\})\cup\{(22222221)_3, (22222222)_3\}.$$
$|B|=|A|-1+2=2^8+1>256$.

Suppose $a,b,c\in B$, $a+b=2c$. Since $A$ is free, (at least) one of $a,b,c$ must be in $\{(22222221)_3,(22222222)_3\}$.

- It is $c$.
  Then $a=2c-b$ $\ge2\times (22222221)_3 -(22222222)_3$ $=(22222220)_3$. Since the biggest element in $A$ is $(11111111)_3$, $a\in\{(22222221)_3, (22222222)_3\}$. By symmetry, so is $b$. So is $c$. Hence $a=b=c$.
- It is not $c$.
  WOLG, let it be $a$. Since $c$ is at most $(11111110)_3$ and $a$ is at least $(22222221)_3$, we have $2c<a\le a+b$. This contradicts with $a+b=2c$.

Hence $B$ is free. Our proof is complete.

#### A free subset of 320 numbers

Here is a free subset of $320$ numbers.

$$ C=E\cup\ F$$
where $E=\{3^6\ell+d \mid \ell\in\{0,1,3\}, d\in D\}$,
$F=\{3^8-1-3^6\ell-d \mid \ell\in\{0,1\}, d\in D\}$,
$\displaystyle{ D=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^5a_i3^i\mid a_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}}$.

$C$ looks like
$\{0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 12, 13,$ $27, 28, \cdots, 3^8-10,$ $3^8-5, 3^8-4, 3^8-2, 3^8-1\}.$

$C$ can be obtained by bidirectional greedy selection, alternating between going forwards from $0$ and going backwards from $3^8-1$. This algorithm/construction can be generalized when the exponent $8$ is replaced by any integer $\ge3$.

$|C|=|D|\times(3+2)=2^6\times5=320$
$\displaystyle{ E\subset\left\{\sum_{i=0}^7a_i3^i\mid a_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}}$ is free.
$F=3^8-1-\displaystyle{\left\{\sum_{i=0}^6a_i3^i\mid a_i\in\{0,1\}\right\}}$ is free.
Let $m_E=0$ be the smallest element in $E$ and $M_E=(10111111)_3$ the biggest element.
Let $m_F=3^8-(1111111)_3$ be the smallest element in $F$ and $M_F=3^8-1$ the biggest element.
We have $2M_E<m_E+m_F \le a +b \le M_E+M_F < 2m_F$ for any $a\in E$, $b\in F$.
Hence $C$ is free.

Answer (score 2):

The greedy algorithm works well. Proceed down the natural numbers in the order $0,1,2,\dots$, and include every element that does not cause a three-term arithmetic progression with two earlier elements. For example, you include $0$, then you include $1$, but you exclude $2$, because $0-1-2$ is a three-term AP. You then include $3$, include $4$, exclude $5$ because of $1-3-5$, exclude $6$ because of $0-3-6$, and so on. It is not too much work; for example, in order to check whether $32$ can be added, you just need to check $16$ previous pairs. That is, you can add $32$ as long as $(30,31)$ are not both present, and same for $(28,30),(26,29)$, and so on down to $(0,16)$.

Here is the result:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
^ ^ x ^ ^ x x x x ^ ^  x  ^  ^  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
x  x  x  x  x  x  ^  ^  x  ^  ^  x  x  x  x  ^  ^
```

Of course, you cannot use the greedy approach to get all the way up to $3^8-1$, but fortunately by now, a pattern has started to emerge. All of the included entries come in pairs. Furthermore, these pairs themselves come in pairs, separated by a single `x`. Then, these pairs-of-pairs themselves come in pairs, separated by four `x`'s. For example, the sequence from $0$ to $4$ is an exact repeat of the sequence from $9$ to $13$. The longer you go, the more patterns you can find like this; the next example is that the sequence from $0$ to $13$ is an exact repeat of the sequence from $27$ to $37$. After staring at these repeats for long enough, you can see how related they are to powers of $3$, and then start to guess how to describe the general pattern.

I hope that this is enough for you to get started. It is a really beautiful pattern, so I want to give you the chance to discover it for yourself.